# Change button add user to TextView friend

Tags: android, social-networking

I'm developping a social app for Android ,when a user click to add another user to become his friend the button change to friend but when i close and un again the app the button add user comes back even if if they are friends ,i have the same issue with my like button , when i click the button change the color but when i restart the color is gone .

Any help would be much appreciated .Thanks.

Comment: You need to store the data of users who are friends somewwhere, in your DB or sharedprefrences and whenever the page is populated you have to check the status whether the user is friend or not and then update the button as per the stored information, do same for the like button

Comment: Do you have any tutorial or something that can help me to do it , because i don't know where to start